# How to change CSS with JavaScript using an if statement?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a subscribe button that has a value of either "subscribe" or "unsubscribe", the value changes when the button is pressed.

However, I also want that when the value is "unsubscribe" the button changes color until the button is pressed again.

**HTML**:

```
<input onclick="change()" type="button" value="Subscribe" id="subscribe- 
   button"></input>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function change()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("subscribe-button");
    if (elem.value=="Unsubscribe") elem.value = "Subscribe";
    else elem.value = "Unsubscribe";
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("subscribe-button");
if (elem.value == "Unsubscribe") {
    document.getElementById("subscribe-button").style.color = "blue";
    document.getElementById("subscribe-button").style.backgroundColor = 
"white";
    document.getElementById("subscribe-button").style.borderColor = 
"blue";
}
```

But that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Less code if you just toggle a class and use style rule for that additional class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input onclick="change()" type="button" value="Subscribe" id="subscribe-button"></input>
```

what happens is that js is executed but the change function is called later

```
function change() {
var elem = document.getElementById("subscribe-button");
if (elem.value == "Unsubscribe") {
    elem.value = "Subscribe"
} else {
    elem.value = "Unsubscribe";
    elem.style.color = "blue";
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    elem.style.borderColor = "blue";
}
```

}

hope this works by the way a more systematic responsive is to warp all styles in a stylesheet class and append the class using js

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you not add CSS properties using JavaScript, you can do it by adding removing classes.

```js
function change()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("subscribe-button");
    if (elem.classList.contains('unsubscribe')) {
      elem.value = "Subscribe";
      elem.classList.remove('unsubscribe');
    } else {
      elem.value = "Unsubscribe";
      elem.classList.add('unsubscribe');
    }
    
    
    
}
```

```css
.unsubscribe {
 color: blue;
 background-color: white;
 border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input onclick="change()" type="button" value="Subscribe" id="subscribe-button" />
```